# How would you implement dereferencing of pointers in z3

Tags: c, z3, z3py

Trying to analyze some C programs with z3 in python, and got into trouble with pointers. I am working with terms like:

```
float * buffer = (float*)malloc(5*sizeof(float))
```

I interpret buffer as a `BitVec(32)` value
so `*buffer` should be `Real()`. 
That should be ok, but what assertions should I write for the terms like

```
*(buffer+3) or *(buffer+i)
```

How should be the assertions written if I am indexing out like

```
*(buffer-1) or *(buffer+10)
```

Comment: If you're programming in C, then use only that tag. Don't spam with unrelated tags (language or otherwise).

Comment: Also, in C it is not necessary to cast the return value of `malloc` - it can only mask errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to encode the program heap as a map `H` from locations to values. In Z3, the array theory can be used to encode maps.

Pointers/addresses are integer locations, integer arithmetic encodes pointer arithmetic; this would allow constraints such as `H(buffer + i) > 0` in your encoding. If you were to encode an OO-language, you could use the pair (receiver, field name) to encode addresses. E.g. `H(r, f) > 0` would correspond to `r.f > 0`. Note that this map encoding naturally accounts for aliasing, e.g. if `buffer1 == buffer2` and `i == 3` then `H(buffer1 + i) == H(buffer + 3)`.

See the paper [Heaps and Data Structures: A Challenge for Automated Provers](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-22438-6_15) for an interesting comparison of map-based heap encodings.

Map-based encodings are typically used by tools based on verification condition, such as [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), [Dafny](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/dafny-a-language-and-program-verifier-for-functional-correctness/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fdafny#) and [Boogie](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/boogie-an-intermediate-verification-language/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprojects%2Fboogie%2F#). Tools based on symbolic execution, such as [Silicon](https://bitbucket.org/viperproject/silicon) (which is part of the [Viper verification infrastructure](http://viper.ethz.ch/)) and [VeriFast](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~bart.jacobs/verifast/) typically use a different encoding; see, e.g. [Heap-Dependent expressions in separation logic](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2163916) .